# Pivot using join, case when, and to char in Oracle doesn't show the right result

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to join these tables:

Table A:

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| James | 01 |
| Jonah | 02 |

Table B:

| ID | Score | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 80 | 12-Nov-2022 |
| 01 | 90 | 24-Dec-2022 |
| 02 | 70 | 12-Nov-2022 |
| 02 | 60 | 24-Dec-2022 |

Select result that I want:

| Name | Score of Nov | Score of Dec |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | 80 | 90 |
| Jonah | 70 | 60 |

Select result that I get:

| Name | Score of Nov | Score of Dec |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | 0 | 0 |
| Jonah | 0 | 0 |

This is my query:

```
select 
    a.name,
    sum(case when b.date = 'Nov' then B.Score else 0 end) as Nov,
    sum(case when b.date = 'Dec' then B.Score else 0 end) as Dec
from 
    table_a a
join 
    table_b b on a.id = b.id
group by 
    a.name;
```

I also tried:

```
select 
    a.name,
    sum(case when To_char(b.date, 'dd-mon-yyyy') = 'Nov' then B.score else 0 end) as Nov,
    sum(case when To_char(b.date, 'dd-mon-yyyy') = 'Dec' then B.score else 0 end) as Dec
from 
    table_a a
join 
    table_b b on a.id = b.id
group by 
    a.name;
```

But to no luck. I don't know how to use the `WHERE` in to char and `CASE WHEN`, especially I just want to take the month. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare a date with the 'Nov' and 'Dec' strings, you should rather extract the month from the date and apply the comparison:

```
SELECT a.Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM b.Date_)=11 THEN B.Score ELSE 0 END) as Nov_,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM b.Date_)=12 THEN B.Score ELSE 0 END) as Dec_
FROM       table_a a
INNER JOIN table_b b
        ON a.ID = b.ID
GROUP BY  a.Name
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/H62aeR87).